# Why is the bottom of my compressed JPEG sprite truncated?

Tags: html, css, css-sprites

I have a very simple bit of code to display a single image from a sprite.

When the “Sprite“ only has one image, it works perfectly. When there are three images, even though the first image is exactly the same size, the bottom of the image is truncated. I can’t think of any reason why this is happening. I put the img inside a div and gave the div a height of 100%, but this didn’t make any difference.

Here’s my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<style>

#img1 {
  background: url("bates-sprite.jpeg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  object-fit: none;
}
#img1 {object-position: 0 0;
  width:  816px; // full size 3264
  height: 612px; // full size 2448
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div style="height: 100%">
<img id="img1" src="bates-sprite.jpeg">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

[image: Full image displayed]

[image: Bottom of image truncated]

Comment: Why are you setting a background and src on an image. Either you should use src on <img> tag or use a div for background using css

Comment: The image will be set as background to a button, inside a figure.

Comment: I'm not seeing any button here is the code, I guess it is incomplete.

Comment: I cut the code down to Expose the root problem.

Comment: Never set a background on an image, this doesn't make any sense. Use a div for it to show your problem

Comment: I have to set background: url("bates-sprite.jpeg"); because I’m using a sprite.

Comment: Re "`width:  816px; // full size 3264`": `//` is not a valid comment character sequence in CSS (only the C-style one is, `/*  */`). This is also indicated by the weird ***syntax highlighting***. It *will* break in some browsers (e.g., it may ignore all or part of the rest of the CSS (terminate parsing)).

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know why the multiple image sprite behaves differently, but setting `style="height: 100vh;”` solves the problem.